# communication between threads in threadpool

Tags: java, multithreading, hashmap, threadpool

Assume I have one threadpool and each thread is running following method:

```
void runMe(HashMap myHash){
   ...
   myHash.remove(keyToBeRemoved);
   ...
}
```

My question is; should not `myHash` be the same in all threads at the beginning? Because my second thread does not have the key `keyToBeRemoved`. I was wondering why.

Comment: If you use the same map in all the threads, and the first one removes this key, obviously the other threads won't find the key in the map (assuming access to the map is properly synchronized)

Comment: You share a single map between several threads. If you don't want the map to be shared, then don't share it. Create a new copy of the map for each thread. I don't want to be rude, but multi-threading is a very very complex matter. If you don't understand how Java passes references to objects, it's probably not a good idea to mess with multithreading.

Comment: To expand on JB Nizet, HashMap is _not_ thread-safe.  You're pretty lucky just to have the key missing.  If two threads tried to do the remove simultaneously, all kinds of strange things could happen.  A NullPointerException would be one of the better results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `myHash` *reference* may be the same for all threads, but when the first thread executes

```
myHash.remove(keyToBeRemoved);
```

then *the hash map* (which all references refer to) will no longer have that mapping.

Comment: what if each thread creates new Hashmap and calls runMe() method?

Comment: Then obviously each *reference* will be unique, and `myHash.remove` won't affect the other threads.

Comment: you considered hashmap is shared, anvarik didn't mention that, so asked.

Answer (score 1):

HashMap hm => Depends on your program. If you are using it shared among threads, it will be modified by each thread simultaneously and you have provide concurrency.

keyToBeRemoved => same as above